# GAE Blobstore: upload blob along with other text fields

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, app-engine-ndb

I have a form that includes, between text fields, an element to upload a picture.
I want to store the blob in the blobstore and reference it in my model (`ndb.Model`) using `ndb.BlobKeyProperty()`.
The method shown in [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob) uses an upload handler (`UploadHandler`) which is called from the link created in this way:

```
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
```

`upload_url` is the form action in the page created to upload the blob. However, my form includes other fields that are not processed in the `UploadHandler` post method. 
The temporary solution I found was to create a handler for my form that inherits from my BaseHandler AND from BlobstoreUploadHandler:

```
class EditProfile(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler, BaseHandler)
    def get(self):
        params['upload_url'] = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_blob1')
        ... fields ...

    def post(self):
        upload_blob = self.get_uploads()
        blob_key = upload_blob[0].key()
        value_field1 = self.request.POST.get('field1')
        value_field2 = self.request.POST.get('field2')
        value_field3 = self.request.POST.get('field3')
        ...
```

This method works, except that I have to define a new handler in `main.py` for each page that has a blob to be uploaded:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ ('/upload_blob1', handlers.EditProfile),
                                ('/upload_blob2', handlers.EditBlob2Handler),
                                ('/serve/([^/]+)?', handlers.ServeHandler) ], 
                                debug=os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Dev'), config=webapp2_config)
```

Question: how can I use one single upload handler (for instance: `UploadHandler`) that is called from different pages to perform the upload blob task? I know this might be very simple for an experienced GAE programmer, but I haven't found a solution around.

Comment: So far everything you've entered is correct.  If you have two separate forms that both need to upload a blob, they'll need two separate handlers.  It only makes sense to use the same handler if all the form fields are the same.

Comment: What if I want to have only one upload handler (`UploadHandler`) which is used by both `handlers.EditProfile` and `handlers.EditBlob2Handler`? Is that possible? How?

Comment: If the forms being submitted for the two handlers are the same, and the two handlers are the same, then you can just direct them both to the same url by passing the appropriate url as the destination to create_upload_url().  If the handlers are different and do different things, then this would be a dumb question.

Comment: You just gave the right answer for the wrong question. I guess I have now a better picture on how things work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes you can.

The handler is just the code that parse your upload form and then performs action based on the information.

Technically, you can have one form even for different uploads, but it really depends on how different and whether or not you wish to split up the code.

For example, if your form1 uploads "First name" "Last name" "Favorite color" and your form2 uploads "First name" "Last name" "Favorite number", then your /upload handler can simply read the parameter and process them differently.

If (req.getParameter("Favorite_Number") != null) {Do whatever}

Else if (req.getParameter("Favorite_Color") != null) {Do whatever}

It's just a matter of design. Your question of whether or not you CAN use one handler, the answer is yes. However, it's recommended to use different ones if they are functionally different.